# Generating end-point descriptions in Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

Servant [provides a way](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Docs.html) to generate documentation from the API definition. However, I see no way of (informally) documenting the functionality of each end-point. For the example used in the link above, the generated documentation contains:

```
## Welcome

This is our super webservice's API.

Enjoy!

## GET /hello

#### GET Parameters:

- name
     - **Values**: *Alp, John Doe, ...*
     - **Description**: Name of the person to say hello to.


#### Response:
```

In the example above, what I miss is a way of documenting what the `GET /hello` end-point does, this is, I would like to have a way to augmenting the API docs with an informal description of each end-point.

```
## Welcome

This is our super webservice's API.

Enjoy!

## GET /hello

Send a hello message to the given user. /<-- My description.../

#### GET Parameters:

- name
     - **Values**: *Alp, John Doe, ...*
     - **Description**: Name of the person to say hello to.


#### Response:
```

My guess is that this will require tagging the different end-points to identify them uniquely, something that as far as I know Servant does not support. However, I'm wondering how to solve this problem with what is available as of now.

Comment: I looked at that documentation mechanism briefly.  It wasn't useful enough for me to justify any real time investment so I just host a static page, hand crafted and manually kept up-to-date with the API.  In my case it helps that the API pretty much never changes (perhaps 1 change in over a year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for can be found in the `Servant.Docs` module of `servant-docs` ([here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-docs-0.10/docs/Servant-Docs.htm)).

If you use the `docsWith` function, you can supply an `ExtraInfo` object for the api you are documenting:

```
docsWith :: HasDocs api => DocOptions -> [DocIntro] -> ExtraInfo api -> Proxy api -> API
```

I believe that the point of `docsWith` is to allow you to supply extra endpoint documentation, as you are asking. There is a `Monoid` instance for `ExtraInfo`, so it looks like you can build separate `ExtraInfo` objects for each endpoint in your api, then `mappend` them together, and pass this to `docsWith`.

To build `ExtraInfo`, use the `extraInfo` function:

```
extraInfo :: (IsIn endpoint api, HasLink endpoint, HasDocs endpoint) => Proxy endpoint -> Action -> ExtraInfo api
```

The documentation (linked to above) has an example of how one would go about using the `extraInfo` function.

Comment: Thanks with your tips I was able to add custom `notes`. It differs from what I wanted in that adding a note adds a new section, but it is better than nothing. Now I'm gonna try to make this work on generated Swagger docs, but that's another story.